# Can’t add deployed web part to SharePoint (web part missing)

Tags: web-part, deployment

I’m trying to add my first web part to the working environment and have some problems with the deployment. I clicked on my development machine `release` and copy the `*.wsp` file from the  `"bin/release"` folder to the working environment SharePoint desktop.

I deployed the `*.wsp` file with following command:

```
Add-SPSolution C:\User\admin\Desktop\ProjectName.wsp
Install-SPSolution -Identity ProjectName.wsp -WebApplication http://sharepointportal –GACDeployment
```

from the working environment SharePoint. Everything works fine.

After that I activated the feature in SharePoint and tried to add it to a page. Here occurs the error. If I try to add the web part, SharePoint tells me, that the web part element was deleted in the catalogue. If I went to "All Web Parts", the web part is listed, but if I click on it, SharePoint tells me that the web part is missing, what went wrong?

In `C:\windows\assembly`, the assembly exists and also the `SafeControl` entry in web.config exist.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=314328d2d4e8850d" Namespace="ProjectName.Dictionary" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

What I did wrong?

**Additional informations**

I'm honestly a little bit confused, because I have renamed the Feature from, I think, Feature1 to Dictionary, maybe there is the problem.

Yes, the web part class is public:

```
public class Dictionary : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
{...}
```

Here a small dump from my project folder:

[image: Project Folder]

The `Dictionary.feature` contains:

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="Titel" Id="..." Scope="Site">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementFile Location="Dictionary\Dictionary.webpart" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Dictionary\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

The `Package.package` contains:

```
 <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="ProjectName.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
      <SafeControls>
        <SafeControl Assembly="ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...." Namespace="ProjectName.Dictionary" TypeName="*" />
      </SafeControls>
    </Assembly>
  </Assemblies>
  <TemplateFiles>
    <TemplateFile Location="CONTROLTEMPLATES\ProjectName\Dictionary\DictionaryUserControl.ascx" />
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\ProjectName\Button.css" />
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\ProjectName\Dialog.aspx" />
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\ProjectName\javascripts\jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\ProjectName\Site.css" />
  </TemplateFiles>
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="ProjectName_Dictionary\Feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
```

Does that help further?

Greetz

Comment: Does your project include the elements.xml, the classfile, and the webpart file for the webpart?

Comment: Did you mark the webpart class as Public?

Comment: See my **Additional informations**. Is it really enough just to deploy the `*.wsp`? Thanks. Greetz

Comment: Btw, what is the different between the `Release "/bin/release"` and the `package  (pkg, pkgobj, obj)`. Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got it! The problem occurs after I updated the web part. I updated the wep part with:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity ProjectName.wsp -LiteralPath C:\test\ ProjectName.wsp –GACDeployment
```

and after that I use:

```
Enable-SPFeature FeatureName  -Url http://...
```

to update the web part. Now share point doesn’t find the web part and I get the error from above.

I fixed it with the following steps:

```
1. Uninstall-SPSolution –Identity ProjectName.wsp –WebApplication http://...
2. Check if the Feature is deactivated, removed.
3. Delete the web part from the web part gallery.
4. Remove-SPSolution –Identity ProjectName.wsp
```

Did I something wrong with the update? Everytime I update the web part, the error occur.

**Edit:**

If I deactivate the web part in the global site collection, update it with Update-SPSolution and activate it, everything works fine!

Thanks everyone. Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same Namespace for webpart and safecontrol entry. Also it make sense to double check the assembly name, public token and version.

Also check the .webpart file and elements - to make sure you have the same values everywhere